# How to install vs code in termux in android phone

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, termux

I am trying to install vs code in termux terminal but its giving me the following error

```
root@localhost ~/c/bin# ls
code-server*
root@localhost ~/c/bin# ./code-server
./code-server: 28: exec: /root/code-server-4.20.0-linux-arm64/lib/node: not found
root@localhost ~/c/bin [127]#
```

I have followed the following procedure from someone on YouTube.

1. apt update && apt-upgrade -y
2. apt install proot-distro
3. Proot-distro list
4. Proot-distro install ubuntu
5. Proot-distro login ubuntu
6. Apt-get install wget
7. Wget https://github.com/coder/code-server/releases/download/v4.20.0/code-server-4.20.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz
8. Tar -xvf code-server-4.20.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz
9. Cd code-server-4.20.0-linux-arm64/bin
   9  export PASSWORD='password'
10. ./code-server

I have installed `npm` and `node`

Here is the output when i check their versions

```
root@localhost:~# npm -v                          
8.19.4
root@localhost:~# node -v
v16.20.2
```

Please help where I am doing wrong or what packages are required

I am on unrooted android phone running version 10

I expected after running `./code-server`  to work just fine by running the vs code locally on localhost:8080

Comment: Have you seen: [How to use Visual Studio Code on an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/230010/3573)